# Kali 2017.2 Graphical login fails

Tags: kali-linux, login

When ever I enter my user and password the same window comes back again and again. It wants user and password back to back. 
I did <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>f3</kbd> and got terminal. I did:

```
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade
apt-get -f install
apt-get dist-upgrade
```

all separately. I tried to remove lightdm and installed it again. But it is a matter of sorrow that I could not fix that problem.The same thing happens every time. What could be the reason behind it and what is the solution for this?

Comment: Were you once able to login to the GUI? Is there anything eye-catching in syslog (`/var/log/syslog`) or the X server log? This could be a graphics problem (but it does not has to be one).

Comment: I don't remember. :( I was running kali for 2 months this is first time when I am facing this trouble.

Comment: Try logging in the GUI. Then head to the console and inspect the syslog using `less /var/log/syslog`. There should be some information about the failed login

Comment: `~/.xsession-errors` (in your user's home directory) is another good place to check for errors. Could be that it's trying to start the desktop, but its failing (and thus you get logged right back out). `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` is a good place to check, too.

Comment: I've run across this kind of thing before. What desktop environment are you running? And what display manager do you have installed? I was having similar issues with KDE till  I installed `sddm`. `/etc/X11/xorg.log` generally includes some indication of what is going on.

Comment: Guys I did less /var/log/syslog and found too many lines which are not understandable for me and other commands are saying error. I couldn't  apply them I think.

Comment: anyone answer plz... I need to get back my web project..I don't have any backup for that...I am unable to login via GUI

Answer (score -1):

```
apt-get --fix-broken install
apt-get autoremove
```